# How do I structure sensor data in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, django, sqlite, time-series

I want to store the sensor data from several weather stations on an SQL-database so that it can be viewed through a django web-page.

To keep the explanation simple, I read a few sensors (bools and float values) from each weather station every few minutes. I also want to store the time stamp of each reading.

What is the best way to structure this data in an SQL database? I would like to keep the system running for years, so it has to be able to store several hundred thousand values. I also need to read these values for display in graphs.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: You've tagged this with both mysql and sqlite.  Which one are you actually using?  It makes a difference to the answer.

Comment: I have not tried anything yet, and I have not 100% decided on database although that seems not to natter much in Django. I will go with Vatev's suggestion, that seems like a simple and efficient structure.

Answer (score 1):

For a start, you can have 2 tables - `stations` and `readings`.

The `stations` table has an auto-increment id field and any other info about the stations that you need / have. E.g.:

```
`id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`lat` DOUBLE NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`lng` DOUBLE NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
...other things
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

The `readings` table contains entries for a single report from a station at a given time (I'm guessing the values will be averaged over a few minutes):

```
`id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`time` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
`id_station` INT NOT NULL,
`temp` DOUBLE NULL,
`humidity` DOUBLE NULL,
`wind_speed` DOUBLE NULL,
`wind_dir` DOUBLE NULL,
`pressure` DOUBLE NULL,
`squirrel_count` DOUBLE NULL,
... other things 
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
INDEX `time` (`time`),
INDEX `id_station` (`id_station`)
```

Depending on the amount of readings and how 'big' your server is, you might be able to use this table to aggredate (e.g. daily) and create a chart, or you might need to pre-aggregate the data in another table for reporting.

E.g: once a day a script/SQL proc runs a query, which aggregates the data for the previous day and inserts it into another table. The second table will be almost the same as the 1-st, except that it will contain only daily averages (instead of few-minute-ish ones).

You can use preaggregation to create multiple tables with different granularity (hourly, daily, weekly...) as needed for your reports. How many and which you will need depends on how fast you want it to run, and the hardware you have.

Comment: Thank yo so much for the reply, Vatev! That was just the kind of answer I was hoping for. Aggregating averages seem like a good solution for long term graphs.